# get_post_thumbnail_id() not getting correct featured image after post edited

Tags: post-thumbnails, wp-api

Hy, everything works fine until I change featured image by editing post, using

`wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),"full")`

I get the url to the original picture, not the new one

Comment: please explain more

Comment: Create a post, add featured image, then edit post and replace the featured image with new one, after that when I call wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),"full") I still get the original image url, not the new one from editing post

Comment: I tested on raw WordPress and did not see any problems. Please test on raw WordPress. If there is a problem on your site, please disable your plugins and test. Probably a plugin caused the problem.